# Unable to insert json arrays from Logstash to mongoDB

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb, logstash, bson

I'm using Logstash 1.5.2
trying to insert datas in MongoDB with logstash-output-mongodb
It works well only when my parsed logs doesn't contain arrays, when the JSON contains array it generates an exception.

Failed to send event to MongoDB
undefined methodbson_type
NoMethodError: undefined method `error_code' for #NoMethodError:0x39794292

> `@cancelled=false>, :exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method`bson_type' for "2015-08-24T12:26:19.664Z":LogStash::Timestamp>, :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/hash.rb:44:in `to_bson'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1341:in`each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/hash.rb:43:in `to_bson'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/encodable.rb:57:in`encode_with_placeholder_and_null'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/hash.rb:42:in `to_bson'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/array.rb:49:in`to_bson'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:978:in`each_with_index'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/array.rb:46:in `to_bson'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/encodable.rb:57:in`encode_with_placeholder_and_null'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/array.rb:45:in `to_bson'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/hash.rb:46:in`to_bson'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1341:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/hash.rb:43:in`to_bson'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/encodable.rb:57:in `encode_with_placeholder_and_null'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.1-java/lib/bson/hash.rb:42:in`to_bson'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:155:in `serialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:153:in`serialize_fields'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:141:in`serialize_fields'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:70:in `serialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server/connection.rb:123:in`write'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server/connection.rb:122:in`write'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server/connectable.rb:66:in `dispatch'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/loggable.rb:44:in`log'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/loggable.rb:67:in `log_debug'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server/connectable.rb:65:in`dispatch'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/operation/executable.rb:35:in `execute'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool.rb:99:in`with_connection'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server/context.rb:63:in `with_connection'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/operation/executable.rb:34:in`execute'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/operation/write/insert.rb:72:in `execute_write_command'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/operation/write/insert.rb:62:in`execute'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/collection.rb:190:in `insert_many'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/collection.rb:175:in`insert_one'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-mongodb-0.1.4/lib/logstash/outputs/mongodb.rb:56:in `receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:88:in`handle'", "(eval):513:in `output_func'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:243:in`outputworker'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:165:in `start_outputs'"], :level=>:warn}
>   NoMethodError: undefined method`error_code' for #
>           receive at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-mongodb-0.1.4/lib/logstash/outputs/mongodb.rb:60
>            handle at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:88
>       output_func at (eval):513
>      outputworker at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline**strong text**.rb:243
>     start_outputs at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.2.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:165
>   `

Any idea to solve this issue please ?
Thanks !

Comment: The timestamp is in every type i store in MongoDB, and it works for most of them, the problem occurs only for 2 types which contain arrays.
That's why i think it's not related to the timestamp

Comment: Bug reports for the logstash mongodb plugin and for logstash itself have been created. Seems to be a known issue.

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-mongodb/issues/9
https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3482

Answer (score 3):

I have this same error when logstash mongoldb output configuration has

```
isodate => true
```

I have no arrays in my data. Just Nginx access-log data. When I output my data with

```
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

@timestamp looks like this

```
{
"@timestamp" => "2015-09-16T18:49:11.347Z",
}
```

Main issues is that when I output this to mongodb, the data is inserted as string with quotes escaped like this:

```
"@timestamp": "\"2015-09-16T18:14:06.178Z\"",
```

I'm using logstash 1.5.4 and mongodb 3.0.6, and the error I'm getting is

```
:exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `bson_type' for "2015-09-16T18:33:52.474Z":LogStash::Timestamp>, :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bson-3.2.4-java/lib/bson/hash.rb:44:in `to_bson'", [...]
```

I haven't found any solution for this yet.